# Keep getting compilation error while creating the following procedure

Tags: oracle

Create a procedure named 'select_city' which accepts one input parameter user_id of type number and one output parameter city_details of type varchar. This procedure is used to display the city_details of user.If the user is from bangalore then display the city_details as 'User is from Bangalore',or if the user is from chennai then display the city_details as 'User is from Chennai', else display the city_details as 'User is from other cities'.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select_city (  user_id IN  user_details.id%type,
                                city_details OUT VARCHAR2(255) ) 
AS
        BEGIN
        SELECT CASE
        WHEN city = 'Bangalore' THEN 'User is from Bangalore'
        WHEN city = 'Chennai' THEN 'User is from Chennai'
        ELSE 'User is from other cities'
        END tmp_status INTO city_details
        FROM contact cnt 
        WHERE cnt.id = user_id;
        END;
```

Comment: Please hit Edit on your question, select highlight your code and make some use of the button above the text writing box, that looks like `{ }`

Comment: Also, for the rest of your software development life, never again say to another software engineer "I got an error" without including the exact error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OUT` parameter shouldn't have **size**. Remove it.

---

Also (probably not related to error you got), consider using `CREATE OR REPLACE` because any subsequent `CREATE` will fail as the procedure - although invalid - already exists so you'd have to drop it first.

---

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table contact as
  2  select 'Bangalore' city, 1 id from dual;

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure select_city
  2    (user_id       in number,
  3     city_details out varchar2                  --> no size here
  4    )
  5  as
  6  begin
  7    select case
  8      when city = 'Bangalore'  then
  9        'User is from Bangalore'
 10      when city = 'Chennai'    then
 11        'User is from Chennai'
 12      else
 13        'User is from other cities'
 14    end tmp_status
 15    into city_details
 16    from contact cnt
 17    where cnt.id = user_id;
 18  end;
 19  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_citydet varchar2(255);
  3  begin
  4    select_city(1, l_citydet);
  5    dbms_output.put_line(l_citydet);
  6  end;
  7  /
User is from Bangalore

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: OUT or IN or IN OUT does not matter. The formal parameters are not given the sizes. But only the data types.